# Can the coverletter writing window be non-modal?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I want to be able to view posting underneath the coverletter writing window -- but you actually can't.  You have to blink it on and off.. it is great that it remembers what you wrote (I always CTRL+C it anyway), and the gray overlay kinda blocks the text also

Comment: TUMBLEWEED.. AWARDED.